# Force file creation time for all files transferred to a directory

Tags: java, files

Is there a way in Linux to change the creation/last access time/last modified time by default, whenever new files are transferred or copied.

Currently, I need to poll a directory for files and process files First in First out basis (FIFO).

If the files are transferred from different environments eg: windows (with time stamp preserved), the file time will be the file creation time by default.

So while polling, i get a list of files & if i try to sort the files by time and get the earliest file arrived, i only get the file which was created earlier, not transferred earlier.

Is there a setting in linux which can force setting the file creation times for all the incoming files.

thanks.

Comment: You mean you want the creation date of every file copy to become the date when you copied it instead of the date when the original was created?

Comment: Yes, that is what i need. I need the file copy date attribute@ByteCommander Commander

Comment: Not sure, but does one of `cp --preserve=timestamps SOURCE TARGET` or `cp --no-preserve=timestamps SOURCE TARGET` do what you want? YOu should try them both, both results are different from running it without any arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I get the desired result, when i don't preserve time stamp, but since different system place files in the folder, i want to force it at system level, rather than depending upon the third party systems.